# Why is my index not being used in this nested query?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a nested query: an inner geoquery to filter, then an outside query to get the ids of the objects.
Because this query became a speed bottleneck in an important operation, I am working on improving it.

This is where I stand:

- I can't understand why the query won't use an index on the select column.
- When I `EXPLAIN` the query, I see that it is using a **Seq Scan** where I expected it to use the index I created.

## The data sizes

The table has **34k** rows.

This query usually selects a couple hundreds of rows, but in this new particularly large case it **selects 5k rows**.

## The query

### Original version

The query was:

- Querying for objects within an area (`ST_WITHIN`);
- Then selecting the parent_id of the object;
- Then selecting all the objects whose id or parent_id were in the list.

The complicated part is that the table has composite objects, that are "linear objects" ¹ made up of child objects. And if some of their child objects are in the area, we want to select the parent object and all the siblings.

¹ (Lines, pipes, etc; bBézier curves built by using several child objects as... nodes.)

```
SELECT id
FROM public.world_objects
-- where the root_id is in...
WHERE COALESCE(parent_id, id) IN (
    -- select the root_id: parent_id, or the id if no parent_id.
    SELECT COALESCE(parent_id, id)
    FROM public.world_objects
    WHERE is_deleted = false
        -- COALESCE to '' because we cannot compare NULL using an equals sign.
        AND COALESCE(public.world_objects.label_type, '') = COALESCE('80624e39-96b8-4058-a61e-5171060105a6', '')
        AND ST_DWithin(
            ST_SetSRID(st_point(-12.3456788012345, 12.3456788012345), 4326),
            ST_SetSRID(st_point(longitude, latitude), 4326),
            100000, false)
        AND internal_type_description NOT IN ('Chain', 'Flightpath', 'Line', 'Pipe'));
```

### Current version

To speed this process up, we are computing and persisting `COALESCE(parent_id, id)` into `root_id`.
A trigger `before insert or update` sets the value.

(We can't use a generated column because that's only for pg12+, and we have a server that we can't yet upgrade from pg10.)

So we changed the query to:

```
SELECT id
FROM public.world_objects
WHERE root_id IN (
    SELECT root_id
    FROM public.world_objects
    WHERE is_deleted = false
        -- COALESCE to '' because we cannot compare NULL using an equals sign.
        AND COALESCE(public.world_objects.label_type, '') = COALESCE('80624e39-96b8-4058-a61e-5171060105a6', '')
        AND ST_DWithin(
            ST_SetSRID(st_point(-12.3456788012345, 12.3456788012345), 4326),
            ST_SetSRID(st_point(longitude, latitude), 4326),
            100000, false)
        AND internal_type_description NOT IN ('Chain', 'Flightpath', 'Line', 'Pipe'));
```

This sped the process up from 1m:20s (!!) to 0m:10s.
But that's still a lot.

I am aiming for a magnitude not above 0m:0.01s = 100ms.
I think that this must be feasible, for a table with less than 100k rows. Surely I am doing something wrong.

## Explaining the query

When the improved query is `EXPLAIN`ed, the weight seems to be on joining the inner query with the outer query:

[image: the EXPLAIN of the improved query]

I added an index on the root_id, but it does not seem to be used?!?

```
CREATE INDEX "world_objects_IX_root_id" ON public.world_objects USING btree (root_id)
```

## Confusion

What's worse is that a co-worker can speed the query up by running `vacuum` after adding the index.
But not me in my machine, following exactly the same steps.

We have the same PG version, but different PostGIS versions:

- `PostgreSQL 12.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`
- PostGIS

  - I have `POSTGIS="3.1.0 3.1.0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.9.0-CAPI-1.14.1" PROJ="7.1.1" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"`
  - and they have 3.0.1

But the inner query is fast, so I don't think that the different PostGIS version is the source of the problem.

## Conclusion, questions

- Shouldn't the root_id index be used in the query?
- Are we doing something wrong? What should be done differently? :(
- Is this behaviour explainable?

Comment: My answer resolves the issue, but I don't know how or why... I would treasure an answer that explained the why and the how. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I was typing and re-typing the question, I noticed this on the EXPLAIN:

[image: the EXPLAIN hints at inner_unique=false]

... and decided to try making the inner query not return repeated values. It worked!

```
SELECT id
FROM public.world_objects
WHERE root_id IN (
    select distinct root_id
    FROM public.world_objects
    WHERE is_deleted = false
        -- COALESCE to '' because we cannot compare NULL using an equals sign.
        AND COALESCE(public.world_objects.label_type, '') = COALESCE('80624e39-96b8-4058-a61e-5171060105a6', '')
        AND ST_DWithin(
            ST_SetSRID(st_point(-12.3456788012345, 12.3456788012345), 4326),
            ST_SetSRID(st_point(longitude, latitude), 4326),
            100000, false)
        AND internal_type_description NOT IN ('Chain', 'Flightpath', 'Line', 'Pipe'));
```

I don't really know why.
The EXPLAIN on the Nested Loop still says "Inner-Unique" false...
But the query now skips "materialize" and uses an Index Scan instead of Seq Scan, and it's fast. ‍♀️

[image: the EXPLAIN of the fast query]